# PHP - Extracting variable data from a form

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, placeholder

I have the following code:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
            <tr class="tr_top">
                <!-- <th class="th_left_top">Message:</th> -->
                <td class="td_top">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="msg" placeholder="<?php if (isset($_POST['encode'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);} else { echo " Your message here. ";} ?>" onfocus='this.select()'></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_mid">
                <!-- <th class="th_left_mid">Shift Parameter:</th> -->
                <td class="td_mid">
                    <input type=text class="form-control input_mid" name="offset" placeholder="<?php if (isset($_POST['encode'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['offset']);} else { echo " Enter a number. ";} ?>">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_bottom">
                <!-- <th class="th_bottom empty"></th> -->
                <td class="td_bottom">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="encode" value="Encode">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="decode" value="Decode">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type=button value='Clear' onclick='this.form.elements.msg.value=""' </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- close table-responsive -->
</form>

<p>Original message: 

                <?php

                $string = $_POST['msg'];
                echo "<p class='string ital'>" . $string . "</p>";
                $newstring = $string;

                $sp = $_POST['offset'];
                //$offset = $sp % 26;

                //$encode = $_POST['encode'];
                $decode = $encode - $offset;

                //echo "<p>sp = " . $sp . "</p>";
                //echo "<p>offset = " . $offset . "</p>";
                //echo  "<p>decode = " . $decode . "</p>";

                for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
                    $ascii = ord($string[$i]);
                    for ($j=0; $j < $sp; $j++) {
                        if ($ascii == 90) { //uppercase bound
                            $ascii = 65; //reset back to 'A' 
                            } 
                        else if ($ascii == 122) { //lowercase bound
                            $ascii = 97; //reset back to 'a' 
                            } 
                        else {
                            $ascii++;
                        }
                    }
                    $newstring[$i] = chr($ascii);

                }
                echo "<p>Encoded message:</p>";

                if (isset($_POST['encode'])) {
                    echo "<p class='string ital'>" . $newstring . "</p>";
                } elseif (isset($_POST['decode'])) {
                    echo "<p class='string ital'>" . $decode . "</p>";
                } else {
                    //echo "<p class='string ital'></p>";
                    //echo "<p class='string ital'></p>";
                }               

                ?>
```

What I am looking to do is a user enters a message and a number in a textarea and input. Code then runs that shifts the values of each letter in the string. I'm trying to get the textarea placeholder to print the encoded message in place of the placeholder when "encode" is pushed. For the input, I achieved this with this code:

> placeholder=""

For the textarea, I am trying to get the variable $newstring to print as the placeholder. I have:

> placeholder=""

I want $_POST['msg'] to be $_POST[$newstring] but it won't work.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: @ZombieBunnies, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a possible solution for your problem - see code below. You can find a working copy of this at http://www.floris.us/SO/codeForm.php

The key to solving your specific problem is right near the bottom; I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms['codeForm'].codeMsg.value = <?php echo '"'.$newString.'"'; ?>;
document.forms['codeForm'].msg.value = <?php echo '"'.$string.'"'; ?>;
</script>
```

to take the value of a php variable and put it in an input area of the form.

```
<html>
<form class="form-inline" name="codeForm" role="form" method="post">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table>
            <tr class="tr_top">
                <!-- <th class="th_left_top">Message:</th> -->
                <td class="td_top">
                    Plain text message<br>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="msg"
                      <?php 
                       if (isset($_POST['encode'])) {
                         echo 'value = "'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']).'"';
                       } 
                       else {
                         echo 'placeholder = "Your message here"';
                       } 
                       ?>
                       onfocus='this.select()'>
                      </textarea>
                </td>
                <td class="td_top">
                    Coded message<br>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="codeMsg" 
                    <?php 
                    if (isset($_POST['decode'])) {
                      echo "value=".htmlspecialchars($_POST['codeMsg']);
                    } 
                    else {
                      echo 'placeholder = "Encoded message here. "';
                    } 
                    ?> 
                    onfocus='this.select()'>
                    </textarea>
                  </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_mid">
                <td class="td_mid">
                    <input type=text class="form-control input_mid" name="offset" 
                    <?php 
                    if (isset($_POST['encode'])) { 
                      echo 'value = "'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['offset']).'"';
                    } 
                    else { 
                      echo 'placeholder = "Enter a number:"';
                    } 
                    ?>
                    >
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tr_bottom">
                <!-- <th class="th_bottom empty"></th> -->
                <td class="td_bottom">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="encode" value="Encode">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type="submit" name="decode" value="Decode">
                    <input class="input_bottom btn btn-default" type=button value='Clear' onclick='this.form.elements.msg.value=""' </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- close table-responsive -->
</form>

<?php
  $string = defaultKey($_POST, 'msg', '');
  $offset = defaultKey($_POST, 'offset', 0);
  $newString = defaultKey($_POST, 'codeMsg', '');
  if(isset($_POST['encode'])) {
    $newString = caesar($string, $offset);
  }
  if(isset($_POST['decode'])) {
    $string = caesar($newString, -$offset);
  }


function caesar($input, $offset) {
  $output = array();
  foreach(str_split($input) as $k=>$i) {
    if (ctype_alpha($i)) {
      $oldChar = strtoupper($i);
      $newChar = chr(((ord($oldChar) - ord('A')) + $offset) % 26 + ord('A'));
      if($i!=strtoupper($i)) { $newChar = strtolower($newChar); }
    }
    else {
      $newChar = $i;
    } // don't do anything with punctuation
    $output[$k]=$newChar;
  }  
  $output = implode($output);
  return $output;
}

function defaultKey($arr, $key, $default) {
  if(isset($arr[$key])) {
    return $arr[$key];
  }
  return $default;
}

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.forms['codeForm'].codeMsg.value = <?php echo '"'.$newString.'"'; ?>;
document.forms['codeForm'].msg.value = <?php echo '"'.$string.'"'; ?>;
</script>       
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works; the only problem is that the encoded string may contain non-printing characters which will cause trouble. I just tested it with the following inputs:

[image]

The problem is that you really need to make sure that the "encoded" string doesn't contain any non-printing characters. It seems that you are implementing a Caesar cypher - to do so efficiently I would use modulo arithmetic (you used a modulo operation on the offset in your code, then commented it out).  Thus

```
$oldChar = strtoupper($input);
$newChar = (($oldChar - ord('A')) + $offset) % 26 + ord('A');
```

If you want, you can add a line

```
if($input!=strtoupper($input)) $newChar = strtolower($newChar);
```

(as far as I know, php doesn't have a built in "isupper()" function...)

Note - this destroys all punctuation etc. If you don't start by testing that you have a valid character you could introduce all kinds of strange characters (in the example below, the space became a comma...). As it is, if your initial code had ascii value 123 in it, you would be toast.

Comment: At the moment, I'm okay with non-printing characters. I can fix that after. I'm really looking for is on POST for the placeholder to be the encoded string. That being said, I appreciate your code; it will come in handy.

Comment: So, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @winthropite - To rephrase your question: you want to make a POST request, using the contents of a php variable as the contents of the POST (rather than the contents of a form). Did I understand that correctly? How do you want to trigger that request - with a click of a button? You might consider rephrasing your question (or even asking a new one) so you are not distracting people with details that do not matter for the problem you really want to solve. Even then, what are you _really_ trying to achieve? The cleaner ("purer") your question, the easier to give a good answer...

Comment: I have a form where x data is entered. The data is stored as variable $string = $_POST['msg'];. That data is then processed and results as $newstring = $string;. I want to feed the variable $newstring back into the form using this code: <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="msg" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['encode'])) { echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['msg']);} ?>" placeholder="Your message here." onfocus='this.select()'></textarea> but instead of $_POST['msg'] I'd like $_POST['$newstring']. Possible?

Comment: Do you want the contents of the placeholder to become whatever was in the variable `$newstring`? Or does the POST request contain another element whose _index_ is the _contents_ of `$newstring`? Or whose index is equal to the literal character string "`$newstring`" (dollar sign and all)?

Comment: I'm looking to have the textarea value to be dynamic. If encode is clicked, textarea will print the encoded value (I want it retained in the textarea field for ease-of-use when decoding). If decode is clicked the textarea text will be the original string before it was encoded.

Comment: And you want to use php for this - so every click generates another request to the server and regenerates the page? It would be cleaner with JavaScript but it can de be done with php. I will write a sample later (not on my phone).

Comment: No worries; I actually figured it out using a different method. Thank you for all of your help!!

Comment: Well - I had actually written a solution, so I put it as an answer "just in case".

Comment: @winthropite - did you intend to accept my 'other' answer? It is far more complete...